# Segmented horizontal line - in spotfire's scatter plot chart

Tags: spotfire

I am looking for a way to draw 3 horizontal lines, that each of them will be drawn with different values over specific x-axis values. For example:

```
Line 1: value= 0.5 for 0 <= x <= 20 
Line 2: value= 1.5 for 20 < x <= 30
Line 3: value= 2.5 for 30 < x <= 35
```

Thanks

Comment: In which chart do you need these lines?

Comment: I am using scatter plot

Comment: did you work out how to do this? i am also interested

Answer (score 1):

Add a line with Lines & Curves/Curve Draw

the formula would look like

if(x>0 AND x<20 , 0.5 ,null)